# Flutter autoroute with firebase authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

I recently tried the flutter [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) package for navigations in my projects because handling the navigations with user authentications is always challenging for me, I always tried to find a way that my path is easy. So in my current projects, I decide to use [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) because it provides a route guard that protects the screen and for authentication, I use firebase auth but the issue is that no resource shows how we can handle firebase authentication with [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) even the officiation documentation doesn't mention route guard in details.

And since I'm new with auto_route and weak in navigations so it's hard to create my solutions. So if there is anyone who uses [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) with firebase authentication so can you please share some code snippets or if you know any article that explains the process step-wise step.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Currently i used auto_route package for my latest project for navigation

1. when your authentication is success then store user data in hive and check if hive contain that key than navigate to next page kindly see below code
2. i done lot's of research than find this way i created single call for managing navigation

   ```
   import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
   import 'package:sspl_admin/src/global/user_data_util.dart';
   import 'package:sspl_admin/src/model/user_modal.dart';
   import 'package:sspl_admin/src/utils/hive/hive_utils.dart';
   import 'routes.gr.dart';

    @AutoRouterConfig(
      replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
     )
     class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {
       @override
       RouteType get defaultRouteType => const RouteType.material();

       @override
       final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
       AutoRoute(
         path: '/',
         page: MenuBarRoute.page,
         initial: true,
         guards: [AuthGuard()],
       children: [
         AutoRoute(
         path: 'deshboard',
         page: Dashboard.page,
         initial: true,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
        path: 'category',
        page: CategoryRoute.page,
        ),
      ],
    ),
      AutoRoute(
       path: '/login-page',
       page: LoginRoute.page,
     ),
    ];
   }

   class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
     @override
    void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) 
       async {
        // Check if the user is logged in.
        bool isLoggedIn = HiveUtils.isContainKey(HiveKeys.userData);

        // If the user is logged in, allow the navigation to proceed.
        if (isLoggedIn) {
        final UserDataUtils userDataUtils = UserDataUtils();
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = 
        HiveUtils.get(HiveKeys.userData);
        final UserData loginModel = UserData.fromJson(data);
        userDataUtils.setUserData(loginModel);
        resolver.next(true);
     } else {
     // If the user is not logged in, redirect the user to the 
        login 
        page.router.navigate(const LoginRoute());
    }
   }
   }
   ```